# apply css to element using variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am storing element id in a variable globe and then applying css but its not working. if i apply css to 'img' then its works ,but when i am trying to apply with variable its not working . i have check console globe value contains id just css is not getting applied .

```
var selglobe=$('#' + globe);
                      $('#one').remove();
                      $(selglobe).addClass('anam');
                      $(selglobe).css("border","double");
                      $(selglobe).css("border-color","yellow");
                      console.log('HTML Globe value is '+globe);
```

EDIT:

```
var selglobe= $('#' + globe);
$('#one').remove();
selglobe.addClass('anam');
selglobe.css("border","double");
selglobe.css("border-color","yellow");
console.log('HTML Globe value is ' + globe);
```

Comment: Everyone i have correct my code ...  but its not applying css to particular object  by using id??

Answer (score 2):

```
var selglobe = $('#' + globe);
```

Here `selglobe` is already an jQuery object. You don't need to do `$(selglobe)` again to make it a jQuery object.

You can simply do this:

```
var $selglobe = $('#' + globe);
$('#one').remove();
$selglobe.addClass('anam');
$selglobe.css("border", "double");
$selglobe.css("border-color", "yellow");
console.log('HTML Globe value is ' + globe);
```

or better:

```
var $selglobe = $('#' + globe);
$('#one').remove();
$selglobe.addClass('anam').css({border: 'double', borderColor: 'yellow'});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the code below:

```
var selglobe= $('#' + globe);
$('#one').remove();
selglobe.addClass('anam');
selglobe.css("border","double");
selglobe.css("border-color","yellow");
console.log('HTML Globe value is ' + globe);
```

The variable selglobe is turned into a jQuery object at the first line so you do not need to use the `$(selglobe)` afterwards anymore since it is already a jQuery object.

Comment: @KennyDs    i have udated my code ... still its not applying css to that particular object .

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle example ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
                  var selglobe='#' + globe;
                      $('#one').remove();
                      $(selglobe).addClass('anam');
                      $(selglobe).css("border","double");
                      $(selglobe).css("border-color","yellow");
                      console.log('HTML Globe value is '+globe);
```

replace  `var selglobe=$('#' + globe);` with var `selglobe='#' + globe;`

or

```
 var selglobe= $('#' + globe);
$('#one').remove();
selglobe.addClass('anam');
selglobe.css("border","double");
selglobe.css("border-color","yellow");
console.log('HTML Globe value is ' + globe);
```

Comment: That would get the object each time. That is wasteful

Answer (score 1):

Change `var selglobe=$('#' + globe);` to `var selglobe= '#' + globe;`

Comment: That would get the element each time. Waste of processing